# What's the 11th number glyph?

Tags: flash, fonts, adobe-flash-cs3, font-embedding

I see it, but it makes no sense.

[image]

What the heck is the 11th number glyph? For that matter, why does each one have an extra glyph?

This is Flash CS3 Professional edition.

Comment: To the person who voted to close: This is a real question, it can be answered definitively. I just don't know what that answer is.

Comment: Adding to Cyclone's comment, to the person who voted to close: "not a real question" doesn't mean "I don't know either."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra character is the standard space character. The reason why it appears in those character sets should then become obvious ;)

You can verify this with these steps:

1. Deselect everything in the list of character sets
2. Enter 1234567890 in the text field
3. Check that the glyph count is 10
4. Enter a space
5. Check that the glyph count goes up to 11 (literally)
6. Select Numerals [0..9] from the list box
7. Check that the glyph count remains the same

You can do the same for the letter glyphs too.

Additionally, if you combine the lowercase and uppercase glyphs, you'll notice that they don't add up to 54 characters, but 53. There's still only one extra character, which is the space character. <del>Add the set of numbers and the total becomes 63, rather than 64 or 65.</del> OK I checked, and combining the letter and number glyphs actually results in 64, not 63 or 65. I don't know in that case — it might have to do with character encoding, or with how Flash handles kerning of glyphs between letters, numbers and whitespace, but I can't say anything for sure.

Comment: This applies to all versions of Flash which the character embedding dialog box appears in.

Comment: I wouldn't normally consider space to be a numeral, but I guess it does make sense for formatting and such. Thank you for the in-depth analysis.